# Prevent "popping" at end of sound in Pygame.mixer

Tags: python, audio, pygame

This has been solved - see solution at bottom.

While using pygame.mixer, every time a sound finishes playing (whether queued in a channel, not queued but still played via a channel, or played directly via `Sound.play()`), an audible "popping" noise can be heard. Is there any way to prevent this?

Example code:

```
import math
import pygame
import array

pygame.mixer.init()

rawArr=[]
for i in range(41000):
    freq1=int(math.sin(i/220.0*math.pi*2)*32767.0)
    if i>40900: freq1=int(freq1*(41000-i)/100.0) #Solution - see Final Solution
    rawArr.append(freq1)

sndArr=array.array('h',rawArr)

snd=pygame.mixer.Sound(sndArr)

snd.play()
```

Update: Fading the sound out causes no noticeable difference. Tested by using `mixer.fadeout(fadeTime)`, `Sound.fadeout(fadeTime)`, and `Sound.play(0,maxTime,fadeTime)` for `fadeTime=1,10,100,200,1000` and `maxTime=0,1,10,100,1000`.

Update 2: Neither `mixer.stop()` nor `mixer.pause()` remove the popping sound.

Update 3: Implementing a manual fadeout by slowly reducing the volume is effective with sufficiently slow fade times, however it is ineffective for fade times of less than about .1 seconds. Furthermore, during the fade time, there is a series of smaller "clicks", which, while quieter than the original, remain audible and are more numerous than the original "popping". Test code, which was appended to the end of the original code:

```
while snd.get_volume():
     snd.set_volume(snd.get_volume()-0.005)
     pygame.time.wait(5)
```

FINAL SOLUTION: Thanks to user msw, was able to remove "popping" by implementing a manual fadeout within the raw audio data. `if i>40900: freq1=int(freq1*(41000-i)/100.0)` was added to the generation loop - this approximately 0.0024 second fade time was just about the shortest that could be used before "popping" occurred. The example code has been updated with the fixed code.

Comment: I'd suspect a bad sound card or flaky driver. I don't think it is your code. Try it on a different machine.

Comment: @msw I have had no audio issues on any other programs, but I will test it on a different machine when I have the opportunity. It could be that Python and my driver are interacting poorly.

Comment: What happens if you play these sounds in something other than pygame? If a sound file ends with a high amplitude, accurately playing it requires a "jump off the cliff" when it goes from 32767 to 0. This transition results in a quick burst of all frequencies, or a "pop". Even songs that end abruptly are mastered with a tail fade-out for just this reason. You may find it useful to fade out your own sounds with a real audio editor (such as Audactiy) first.

Comment: @msw This was the problem - I never knew that abruptly turning off the sound would cause this, although I really should have suspected it, what with speakers being physical devices. Even an approximately 0.0025 second fade time was enough to prevent the "popping", accomplished by adding `if i>40900: freq1=int(freq1*(41000-i)/100.0)` into the audio generation loop. Thank you! Could you put this in an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as the "dread audio cliff of noise".

When you have a digital signal which is higher than 0 and you abruptly cut it off, the waveform must plummet to 0. As people who deal with analog signals will tell you, the digital cliff has (in principle) all frequencies present at some amplitude. This transition sounds like a "pop" by the time it gets to the speakers.

Almost all audio is mastered so that the amplitude is faded to zero by the time the sample ends. If your sample doesn't have this characteristic, fade the sample to zero upon playback. As was noted by the OP, even a 2.5 millisecond fade can be enough to avoid the pop.

Comment: Actually "dread audio cliff of noise" is a term that I've never seen written nor heard, therefore by "known as" I mean "known as in my mind and now perhaps yours as well".